# Ratio smoothing with delta time in JavaScript is buggy

Tags: javascript, timedelta, easing

Smoothing normally works as follows:

Some variable `v` has a target `t`. Every tick, `v` makes progress toward `t` based on a ratio. For example, a ratio of 2:3 or ⅗ will use this formula:

```
v=(v*3+t*2)/5;
```

Here you multiply the variables to make the ratio, and then divide it all up to make the smoothing ratio. `t` can be modified as you want and `v` will handle smoothing and output.

So you have delta time. You pick a target framerate and go from there. I figured it out on my own so I might be wrong about some terminology but whatever. In one frame, the smoothing will have progressed by ⅖ which means you have a remainder of ⅗. In two frames, you will have a remainder of ⅗×⅗. And I thought: how could I do that fractionally, though? And then I was like "oh wait, you can just make powers of these." So I just got the idea to use `insertRatioHere**deltaTime` and multiply it by the difference between the current and target state. At first it was something like

```
v=t-v+(v*(0.6**delta))
```

but that didn't really work, so I tried a lot of different formulas with small changes, none of which worked. Here's my current test code:

```html
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>delta</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id=myCanvas width=400 height=300 style="background-color:white;"></canvas>
        <script>
        var ctx=myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var time={first:new Date(),now:new Date(),delta:new Date()};
        time.since=time.now-time.first;
        time.delta=time.delta.getTime();
        const frame=1000/60;
        var lag=100;//change between 0, frame, 100 and other values when desired
        var boxA={xPos:200,yPos:150,xAccel:0,yAccel:0,xSpeed:0,ySpeed:0,speed:0};
        var boxB={xPos:200,yPos:150,xSpeed:0,ySpeed:0,speed:0};
        var keysDown=[];
        var keyBind={upA:{key:87,on:false},leftA:{key:65,on:false},
            downA:{key:83,on:false},rightA:{key:68,on:false},
            upB:{key:38,on:false},leftB:{key:37,on:false},
            downB:{key:40,on:false},rightB:{key:39,on:false}};
        var varLog=[];
        addEventListener("keydown",whenKeyDown);
        addEventListener("keyup",whenKeyUp);
        tick=setInterval(tickBoxA,lag);
        tick=setInterval(tickBoxB,frame);
        function tickBoxA()
            {time.now=new Date();
            time.delta=time.now-time.first-time.since;
            time.since=time.now-time.first;
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.upA.key)){
                if(!keyBind.upA.on){keyBind.upA.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.upA.on=false}
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.leftA.key)){
                if(!keyBind.leftA.on){keyBind.leftA.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.leftA.on=false}
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.downA.key)){
                if(!keyBind.downA.on){keyBind.downA.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.downA.on=false}
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.rightA.key)){
                if(!keyBind.rightA.on){keyBind.rightA.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.rightA.on=false}
            boxA.xAccel=(keyBind.rightA.on-keyBind.leftA.on)*3*((keyBind.upA.on-keyBind.downA.on!=0)?Math.sin(45):1);
            boxA.xSpeed=boxA.xAccel-boxA.xSpeed+(boxA.xSpeed*0.9**(time.delta/frame));
            //boxA.xSpeed=boxA.xAccel+boxA.xSpeed-(boxA.xSpeed*0.9**(time.delta/frame));
            //boxA.xSpeed=boxA.xAccel+(boxA.xSpeed-boxA.xAccel*0.9**(time.delta/frame));
            //boxA.xSpeed=boxA.xAccel+(boxA.xAccel-boxA.xSpeed*0.9**(time.delta/frame));
            boxA.yAccel=(keyBind.downA.on-keyBind.upA.on)*3*((keyBind.rightA.on-keyBind.leftA.on!=0)?Math.sin(45):1);
            boxA.ySpeed=boxA.yAccel-boxA.ySpeed+(boxA.ySpeed*0.9**(time.delta/frame));
            boxA.speed=Math.sqrt((boxA.xSpeed**2)+(boxA.ySpeed**2));
            boxA.xPos+=boxA.xSpeed*(time.delta/frame);
            boxA.yPos+=boxA.ySpeed*(time.delta/frame);
            render()}
        function tickBoxB()
            {if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.upB.key)){
                if(!keyBind.upB.on){keyBind.upB.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.upB.on=false}
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.leftB.key)){
                if(!keyBind.leftB.on){keyBind.leftB.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.leftB.on=false}
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.downB.key)){
                if(!keyBind.downB.on){keyBind.downB.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.downB.on=false}
            if(keysDown.includes(keyBind.rightB.key)){
                if(!keyBind.rightB.on){keyBind.rightB.on=true}
            }else{keyBind.rightB.on=false}
            boxB.xSpeed=(boxB.xSpeed*9+(keyBind.rightB.on-keyBind.leftB.on)*3*((keyBind.upB.on-keyBind.downB.on!=0)?Math.sin(45):1))/10;
            boxB.ySpeed=(boxB.ySpeed*9+(keyBind.downB.on-keyBind.upB.on)*3*((keyBind.rightB.on-keyBind.leftB.on!=0)?Math.sin(45):1))/10;
            boxB.xPos+=boxB.xSpeed;
            boxB.yPos+=boxB.ySpeed;
            render()}
        function whenKeyDown(keyDownEvent){
            check=keyDownEvent.keyCode;
            if(keysDown.findIndex(isSame)==-1)
                {keysDown.push(keyDownEvent.keyCode)}}
        function whenKeyUp(keyUpEvent){
            check=keyUpEvent.keyCode;
            keysDown.splice(keysDown.findIndex(isSame),1)}
        function isSame(num){return num==check}
        function render()
            {ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,300);
            ctx.fillStyle="#F00";
            ctx.fillRect(boxA.xPos,boxA.yPos,20,20);
            ctx.fillStyle="#0F0";
            ctx.fillRect(boxB.xPos,boxB.yPos,20,20);
            varLog.length=0;
            varLog.push("Time:              "+time.since);
            varLog.push("Delta:             "+time.delta);
            varLog.push("Frame accuracy:    "+time.delta/frame);
            varLog.push("Standard framerate is 60FPS");
            varLog.push("Red box target X:  "+boxA.xAccel);
            varLog.push("Red box current X: "+boxA.xSpeed);
            varLog.push("Red box target Y:  "+boxA.yAccel);
            varLog.push("Red box current Y: "+boxA.ySpeed);
            varLog.push("Red box speed:     "+boxA.speed);
            varLog.push("The red box is trying to handle smooth");
            varLog.push("acceleration in delta time");
            varLog.push("and yeah Ｉ　ｍｅｓｓｅｄ　ｕｐ");
            varLog.push("Green box speed X: "+boxB.xSpeed);
            varLog.push("Green box speed Y: "+boxB.ySpeed);
            varLog.push("Green box speed:   "+boxB.speed);
            varLog.push("The green box works as desired at 60FPS");
            varLog.push("Keys pressed:      "+keysDown);
            varLog.push("Red=WASD, green=↑←↓→");
            ctx.font="15px Courier";
            ctx.fillStyle="#000";
            for(run=0;run<varLog.length;run++){ctx.fillText(varLog[run],0,(run+1)*15)}}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? You would help by explaining what it is you're trying to achieve before how you've tried to achieve it.

Comment: I'm trying to make smooth acceleration work in delta time like it does with fixed timing and I tried using powers of the multiplier but it doesn't work every time...
Tried `boxA.xSpeed=boxA.xAccel-boxA.xSpeed+(boxA.xSpeed*0.9**(time.delta/frame));` and variants of that as formulae under that but like yeah. The results don't appear as expected. Acceleration should happen at the same rate as it's made to do without delta time (green box) without messing up. \*sigh\* this is basically the tech service centre I just took all my work and threw it in to see if someone could fix it, so it's no good